Issue with undetected-chromedriver: Browser crashes when navigating to a website
I am encountering an issue when using the undetected-chromedriver library in my script. The browser opens successfully, but when I try to navigate to a website, the browser crashes, and a white screen appears. Could you please help me understand why this is happening and how to resolve it?
import time
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

options = uc.options.ChromeOptions()
driver = uc.Chrome(options=options)

driver.get('https://www.google.com')

time.sleep(5)

I would greatly appreciate any advice or suggestions. Thank you!
Best regards,

is this any website or just a particular one?  If it's a particular one, please provide the URL.

No, every time I enter a URL, the same thing happens!

try/catch the get() call and include the exception in your post.
